# How to find a relation between three terms

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, algebraic-curves

Consider the following three relations:

\begin{align}
X &= Q\cos(\theta)^2 +R\sin(\theta)^2 \\ 
Y &= Q\sin(\theta)^2 +R\cos(\theta)^2\\
Z &= \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)(R-Q)
\end{align}

Can you find a relation $f$ such that $f(X,Y,Z)=0$ ?

$f$ can not depend explicitly on $Q,R,\theta$, however $f$ can be non linear in $(X,Y,Z)$.

Comment: In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/) `R=QQ[c,s,r,q,x,y,z]`
`I=ideal(x-(q*c^2+r*s^2),y-(q*s^2+r*c^2),z-c*s*(r-q),c^2+s^2-1)`
`gens gb I -- matrix {{r+q-x-y, q^2-q*x-q*y+x*y-z^2, s*q-s*y+c*z, c*q-c*x+s*z, c^2+s^2-1,
     s^2*x-s^2*y+2*c*s*z+q-x, c*s*x-c*s*y-2*s^2*z+z}}` i.e. $R+Q-x-y=0, Q^2-Qx-Qy+xy-z^2=0$

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, however I am looking for relations that does **not** depend on $Q$ and $R$. Does your computation means that such relation does not exist ?

Comment: Changing $Q, R$ gives you different cones intersected by different planes, so I'd say so yes.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
X &= Q\cos(\theta)^2 +R\sin(\theta)^2 
\tag{1}\label{1}
\\ 
Y &= Q\sin(\theta)^2 +R\cos(\theta)^2
\tag{2}\label{2}
\\
Z &= \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)(R-Q)
=\tfrac12\,\sin(2\theta)(R-Q)
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

It follows from \eqref{1}, \eqref{2} that
\begin{align} 
X+Y&=R+Q
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
Y-X&=
\cos(2\theta)(R-Q)
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
4Z^2+(Y-X)^2
&=(R-Q)^2
\tag{6}\label{6}
,
\end{align}

so we can express $Q,R$ in terms of $X,Y$ as

\begin{align} 
Q&=
\tfrac12\,\Big(X+Y+\sqrt{4Z^2+(X-Y)^2}\Big)
\tag{7}\label{7}
,\\
R&=
\tfrac12\,\Big(X+Y-\sqrt{4Z^2+(X-Y)^2}\Big)
\tag{8}\label{8}
,\\
\end{align}

Also, considering \eqref{1}, \eqref{2} as
a linear system with $\cos^2\theta,\ \sin^2\theta,$ as two unknowns,
we can find that

\begin{align}
\cos^2\theta&=
\frac{R\,Y-Q\,X}{R^2-Q^2}
=
\frac{R\,Y-Q\,X}{(X+Y)(R-Q)}
\tag{9}\label{9}
,\\
\sin^2\theta&=
\frac{Q\,Y-R\,X}{R^2-Q^2}
=
\frac{Q\,Y-R\,X}{(X+Y)(R-Q)}
\tag{10}\label{10}
,
\end{align}

or

\begin{align}
\cos^2\theta&=
\frac12\,\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{1+\frac{4Z^2}{(X-Y)^2}}}\right)
\tag{11}\label{11}
,\\
\sin^2\theta&=
\frac12\,\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{1+\frac{4Z^2}{(X-Y)^2}}}\right)
\tag{12}\label{12}
.
\end{align}